# Anyone use fido 2 with flutter for login?

Tags: flutter, authentication, flutter-getx, fido

I don't know how to do it. The only document that I searched is this [contrib-fido2-flutter-lib](https://github.com/mojaloop/contrib-fido2-flutter-lib)

If you guys have any instructions or project use Fido 2, can you send me a GitHub link, I really need it :(

And do we need the USB to have Fido like a key too?
Could you send me the docs that you have?

thank you guys very much.